# How to distinguish empty forms apart from bounded forms in a formset?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

In a template, I need to loop through a formset that consists of both bounded and empty forms, but the total number of forms in the formset is fixed. I need a way to distinguish apart bounded and empty forms as they are designed to be presented differently to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When iterating through your formset, check the `is_bound` attribute.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.is_bound

Comment: How could I miss that!? Thanks!